# How to map or import list of lists as associative array (dictionary)

Tags: import, associations, map, dictionary

Trying to play around with Wolfram Mathematica to manipulate data as dictionaries - associative arrays.

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html

I am looking at examples, but cannot find either in Google a simple example to show how to import data from a CSV and map it into a dictionary key value.

Example, I want to map:

```
data = {{"7A37D069", "Copper"}, {"6D2C07C7", "Autograph"}}
```

Into a dictionary, with first element of tuples as key, the others as values.

I want to call an item of the dictionary with something like:

```
data['7A37D069'] #python syntax, don't know the Wolfram Math one
```

I tried with:

```
Map[data, <|data[[All,1]]-->data[[All,2]]|>]
```

and

```
Map[data, <|a --> x|]
```

Could you help me understand the syntax to map a function over data?

I want a dictionary as final result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
AssociationThread @@ Transpose@data
(*  <|"7A37D069" -> "Copper", "6D2C07C7" -> "Autograph"|>  *)
```

---

The `data` in the comment below can be made into an Association as follows:

```
AssociationThread[data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2 ;;]]]
(*
  <|"7A37D069" -> {"Copper"},
    "6D2C07C7" -> {"Autograph"},  
    "848E0A46" -> {"route", "PIC microcontroller", "Composition", 
         "Knight", "Glacier", "Atlas", "Region", "Vision"}|>
*)
```

Comment: Could you explain what it does and make the association generally applicable? 
Given a list of list: `data = {{"7A37D069", "Copper"}, {"6D2C07C7", "Autograph"}, {"848E0A46", 
  "route", "PIC microcontroller", "Composition", "Knight", "Glacier", 
  "Atlas", "Region", "Vision"}}` I would like to make a dictionary where keys are the first element of tuples, and values all the others. How to generalise the "first element" and "other element" syntax, with no need to explicitly write the values as `"7A37D069"` `->` `"Copper"`

Comment: @user305883 Your example `data` had the form `{{key1, val1}, {key2, val2}}`.  `Transpose` transposes the array (like a matrix) to `{{key1, key2}, {val1, val2}}` or generally `{keys, vals}`.  `AssociationThread @@ {k, v}` first becomes `Association[k, v]`, which then creates an `Association` as described in the documentation.  I assumed you know what an `Association` does and how it can act as a dictionary, since you use it in your question. The data in your comment has quite a different structure than the data in the question....

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Your answer is correct for me, but I am still missing a way to map a function onto a dataset. 
**Do you have to make explicit all the key value pairs in the `(* *)` syntax?**
I import a csv file with **thousands of rows**, I want to use the first column as key. What is a compact way to create an Association passing data itself into `(* *)` syntax, **considering that all first elements of tuples (or CSV column) are always keys**?

Comment: @user305883 Maybe one of us is confused: The code between the comments `(* *)` is the output of the line immediately above it.  If `csvdata` is the imported data, then `csvdata[[All, 1]]` would be column 1, and `csvdata[[All, 2 ;;]]` would be columns 2, 3, etc. You can create the dictionary/`Association` with `dict = AssociationThread[csvdata[[All, 1]], csvdata[[All, 2 ;;]]]`.  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: :P me confused - thank you, I thought it was syntax for `Association` `<|...|>` and forgot `(* *)` was to comment out in Mathematica